# Windows phone 8 application type?

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8

I have a couple quick questions about Windows Phone applications. How does one know the type of Windows Phone application? For example, is the WP email client XAML or Silverlight?

The reason I am asking is that I have been assigned the task of writing some automated testing scripts for an already developed application (or WP core app) and I'm not sure which automated scripting method to use (CodedUI vs VSTO Test UI). It's my understanding that CodedUI only works for XAML based applications.

Thanks!

Comment: Silverlight apps use XAML, so what exactly do you need to know? If you have the app's Visual Studio solution you can look inside to see what the contents are (e.g. C# code or VB code).

Answer (score 0):

From just looking at the app I don't think there is anyway to tell.  However, whether it is SilverLight or new Store App (appx) they both support XAML.  If you have the source code you can load it in Visual Studio.  After the project name you will see:

- Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight
- Windows Phone 8.1

The second one is the newer Store App possibly a Universal App.

If you need to know if it is xaml then certianly asking the developer will be the easiest option.  I assume they are both XAML no matter what as I am not aware that WinJS is supported for phone.

One other option that could help you get to what you need to know is if you have the executables.  Silverlight will be an XAP file extension and the new Store App will be have an APPX file extension.

Good luck & Have fun,

Tom